# Security exception unhandled by user code

Tags: asp.net, exception, event-log, system.diagnostics

my code is here

```
 try
                {
                    db.Entry(object).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("MyEventSource", ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
                }
```

and I am getting error when I write ex to Event Log. Error is "Security exception unhandled by user code "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following configuration code to your web.config inside `<system.web>` tag.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="UserName" password="123456789HI987654351"/>
```

You need to set your system username and password and also set authentication mode windows.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="yourUsername" password="Your password"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Unfortunalety, it created another error that is " Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The user name or password is incorrect."

Comment: You need to set your system username and password and also set authentication mode windows.